# How to start Node.js service automatically on CENTOS 6.7?

Tags: node.js

I have two servers running nodejs applications. I did some setting with the first one before. After that setting, when I start the command line, if I run `node` command, I see the service is running.

But I do not remember what I did. So in my second server, anytime I restart command line session, when I type `node` I get `-bash: node: command not found`.

Could anyone remind me please?

NOTE: Please don't tell me this is duplicate. Search for keywords "start, node service, automatically, etc." most of them tell about the use of 'forever'. I know forever (gdi), mine is a lot more stupid question and I don't know the correct terminology just yet.

Comment: Why the down vote. At least you could explain me what was wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/README.md)

For  `pm2` do the following 
Install it using

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

-g installs it globally. Then do following

```
pm2 start app.js --name="api"
```

Once that is done, you can do `pm2 list` to view all running services as follows

[image: pm2 list]

Make pm2 start at boot time

```
pm2 startup
```

This will automatically start your node.js app.

Works for my 4 apps that are in production.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dave, I didn't mean it sorry, but you made yourself receiver of my statement above: "I know forever (gdi)" **:)**     I don't want to restart nodejs applications automatically. I want to start nodejs service itself automatically. I am sure you know the answer

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Dave. But I still can not explain my question. Think simple: there is no app.js or any files at all. I just want the commands like npm, node, nodemon, forever etc. to work as son as I start command line.

Comment: When you say, node - command not found. Means node is not properly installed. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server

Comment: I prefer nvm and add entry at the end of my ~/.zshrc (as I use zsh, you might need to use ~/.bashrc `nvm use 5` this will load node 5.0 each time I start my terminal

Comment: YES. That was what I was trying to understand. I knew you knew it. Thanks Dave.

Comment: Welcome my friend. Happy coding and be awesome!

Comment: don't use forever, it has problems with restarting application, look their github page to see problems

Comment: @B.Y this doesn't even make sense: I just want the commands like npm, node, nodemon, forever etc. to work as son as I start command line.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in with my problem/solution. pm2 showed it was running after boot, but my script wasn't working.  I stopped and saved the pm2 process and resorted to using a service instead, which also didn't work until I inserted ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30 before the ExecStart statement.